# How to use std::thread of C++ 11 under Cygwin GCC 4.7.2

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, cygwin

I've been trying to compile a multithread hello-world program under Cygwin using the newly introduced C++ 11 std::thread feature without success. I compiled and installed GCC 4.7.2 by myself, and the same code works without any problems under Linux with the same version of GCC. The first error I got was that the compiler did not recognize the -pthread flag. After researching on it for a while I noticed someone said on Cygwin this flag should be -lthread. I made the change and that error was gone, but another series of errors occur telling me thread is not member of std. I wonder if it's caused by the wrong configuration of the compiler during installation, or std::thread is simply not supported under Cygwin?

Comment: I haven't looked carefully to be sure, but my guess would be the latter. `std::thread` and company are enough like pthreads that implementation on Linux should be pretty simple. Windows' threading model is enough different that it'll be a fair amount more work for it.

Comment: But there are [pthreads](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) on Windows.

Comment: pthreads support is part of Cygwin - there's no need for pthreads-win32.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies, but I'm still confused. Is there a way to use `std::thread` under Cygwin? A simple answer of no sounds quite bizarre because it is now part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: if you look at the latest mingw release, you'll notice that there are 2 different releases actually: one with std::thread support, and the other one without, so in the GCC port to windows world, I wouldn't think that std::thread support is a given.

Comment: they are going to make a lot of problems this way. If some one want to use std::thread why one should forbid that? if the compiler is C++11 then it must have std::thread else it is not C++11. Then the cygwin part is optional at this point. C++11 is a language standard POSIX is just "3rd party API".

Answer (score -1):

This looks like you did not compile the program with the appropriate standard library flag. If you want to compile for C++11 you should use:

```
g++ --std=c++0x -o ...
```

The `--std` flag sets the appropriate language compatibility level. If this does not help, please post the error messages you got as a source listing.

Comment: Yes as Michael said, g++ starts accepting --std=c++11 flag instead of the old c++0x one from 4.7. I compiled the code with the flag set, and just I said it told me "thread" is not a member of std. The same code compiles without any problem under the Unix environment.